# Is there any (unbounded) fair blocking queue in java?

Tags: java, data-structures, concurrency

Is there any implementation of blocking queue which guarantees fair take() operation if multiple consumers are removing element from the same queue. I checked LinkedBlockingQueue, LinkedTransferQueue and looks like both of them are unfair. ArrayBlockingQueue provides fair operation but its bounded.

Comment: What about ConcurrentLinkedList? (Okay, it's not a 'queue' per say... and I'm not sure if it's any more 'fair')

Answer (score 3):

We can implement an unbounded fair blocking queue using an unbounded queue like ConcurrentLinked queue and a fair Semaphore. The class below doesn't implement all methods from the BlockingQueue interface but just a few of them for demonstration purposes. The main() method is written as a test only.

```
public class FairBlockingQueue<T> {

    private final Queue<T> queue;
    private final Semaphore takeSemaphore;

    public FairBlockingQueue() {
        queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>();
        takeSemaphore = new Semaphore(0, true);
    }

    public FairBlockingQueue(Collection<T> c) {
        queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>(c);
        takeSemaphore = new Semaphore(c.size(), true);
    }

    public T poll() {
        if (!takeSemaphore.tryAcquire()) {
            return null;
        }
        return queue.poll();
    }

    public T poll(long millis) throws InterruptedException {
        if (!takeSemaphore.tryAcquire(millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            return null;
        }
        return queue.poll();
    }

    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        takeSemaphore.acquire();
        return queue.poll();
    }

    public void add(T t) {
        queue.add(t);
        takeSemaphore.release();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FairBlockingQueue<Object> q = new FairBlockingQueue<Object>();
        Object o = q.poll();
        assert o == null;
        o = q.poll(1000);
        assert o == null;

        q.add(new Object());
        q.add(new Object());
        q.add(new Object());

        o = q.take();
        assert o != null;
        o = q.poll();
        assert o != null;
        o = q.poll(1000);
        assert o != null;

        o = q.poll();
        assert o == null;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice and fair solution, although i suggest using PriorityBlockingQueue

Comment: Thanks, Michael. If we want to use something out-of-the-box we can certainly go for a PriorityBlockingQueue, however the PBQ and the suggested above FBQ are different with regards to sorting/ordering. PBQ keeps its elements ordered according to their natural ordering using a priority heap, and taking elements out of a PBQ happens in this particular order, while the FBQ is backed by a ConcurrentLinkedQueue which is a normal FIFO queue.

Comment: BTW, the take() in PriorityBlockingQueue from Java SE 6 is fair to callers as it is implemented with a fair ReentrantLock, but in Java SE 7 it is implemented with a non-fair ReentrantLock and respectively it is not longer fair to callers. Have just checked the sources.

Answer (score 0):

[PriorityBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html)

Answer (score 0):

Fairness policy may be specified for [SynchronousQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html):

> a queue constructed with fairness set
>   to true grants threads access in FIFO
>   order

Comment: Looking at the javadoc for that class it makes me laugh.  For instance clear does nothing

Comment: @Woot4Moo you clearly (pun unintended) don't understand how that class works – it has no capacity at all so it can't be cleared.

Comment: @Jed you clearly don't find the humor in documenting something that does nothing.