# Ordering requests to servlet

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have a servlet that on `doPost` method performs some actions. Also I have some pool of `Connections`(let it be `N` connections) to some web-service that are taken from the pool on each request to my servlet(1 connection per request). In `doPost` method of the servlet I retrieve a connection from the pool, use it(this operation may last too long) and put back it to the pool.

Suppose that `N` connections are made simultaneously to the servlet, so `N` connections will be retrieved from the pool. And while that requests are being processed, `N+1` and `N+2` requests are arrived, so they will wait until releasing of some connection occurs(my pool is backed by `BlockingQueue`).

I want to guarantee that `N+1` request will own the available connection earlier than `N+2` request.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) provides constructor argument to control *fairness* of the queue - when set to `true`, it's guaranteed that threads will get elements of the queue in the same order as they called `take()`.

As far as I understand, use of `ArrayBlockingQueue` with `fair = true` as a backing queue of your pool should be enough for your case.

Comment: ArrayBlockingQueue is backed by a fixed-sized array. Keep in mind of  IllegalStateException.

Comment: what if the size of queue is unknown before instantiation?

Comment: @maks: Since `LinkedBlockingQueue` doesn't have fair option, you'll have to implement your own blocking queue based on fair synchronization primitives. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046838/is-there-any-unbounded-fair-blocking-queue-in-java