# Java BlockingQueue with multiple consumer threads unfair

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue, linkedblockingqueue

I'm creating a resource pool using a (java) LinkedBlockingQueue, where

- the resource elements are equivalent, belong to a pool where their ordering is indifferent.
- the consumers are competing threads grabbing one resource at a time, with a "pull" operation,
  working with the resource, and then giving it back to the pool, with an "add" operation.
- While a particular resource is being used by a consumer thread it must not be available to other consumer threads.

The problem is:  LinkedBlockingQueue *does not make a FIFO of waiting consumers*, and the level of service is not uniform.

Any ideas on the topic ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you ruled out using an off-the-shelf resource pooling library like [Apache commons-pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/)?

Comment: See [Is there any unbounded fair blocking queue in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046838/is-there-any-unbounded-fair-blocking-queue-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your situation may require this type of design, but repeatedly taking resources from a queue and putting them back seems slightly unusual to me.

Couldn't you simple have a fixed pool of workers (each bound to its resources) and use the `LinkedBlockingQueue` for distributing jobs/work instead?

Comment: Well I think that this design applies if it is relatively expensive to create a new resource, or not desirable to create more than N resources for any number of consumers.